# Как в Tkinter узнать позицию курсора и выделенный текст в виджете Entry?

Tags: python, tkinter, текст, курсор

Как в Tkinter узнать позицию курсора и выделенный текст в виджете Entry?

Answer (score 1):

Есть текстовые индексы `Entry`, соответствующие, например, позиции курсора и начала/конца выделения:

> #### INDICES
>
> Many of the widget commands for entries take one or more indices as
> arguments. An index specifies a particular character in the entry's
> string, in any of the following ways:
>
> - `number` - Specifies the character as a numerical index, where 0 corresponds to the first character in the string.
> - `"anchor"` - Indicates the anchor point for the selection, which is set with the `select_from()` and `select_adjust()` widget methods.
> - `"end"` - Indicates the character just after the last one in the entry's string. This is equivalent to specifying a numerical index
>   equal to the length of the entry's string.
> - `"insert"` - Indicates the character adjacent to and immediately following the insertion cursor.
> - `"sel.first"` - Indicates the first character in the selection. It is an error to use this form if the selection is not in the entry window.
> - `"sel.last"` - Indicates the character just after the last one in the selection. It is an error to use this form if the selection is not
>   in the entry window.
> - `@number` - In this form, number is treated as an x-coordinate in the entry's window; the character spanning that x-coordinate is used.
>   For example, `"@0"` indicates the left-most character in the window.

По информации отсюда: [tkinter.Entry](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tkinter.Entry)

Эти индексы можно использовать в некоторых методах Entry, вот пример для вставки текста в позиции курсора: `entry.insert("insert", "Some text")`.

Для получения числовых значений этих индексов можно использовать метод `.index()`.

Полный пример с выводом позиции курсора, начала/конца выделения и выделенного текста:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

entry = Entry()
entry.pack()


def command():
    print("Cursor positon:", entry.index("insert"))
    if entry.selection_present():
        selection_from = entry.index("sel.first")
        selection_to = entry.index("sel.last")
        print(f"Selection from {selection_from} to {selection_to}")
        print("Selected text:", entry.get()[selection_from:selection_to])


button = Button(text="Press me", command=command)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```